# oracle 10g - encrypting existing column - Transparent Data Encryption

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, transparent-data-encryption

It's possible encrypting existing column  without lost and rewrite data?

I've few milion of record and it's very important not lost data.

Comment: Why would you lose any data?

Comment: I do not know if they get lost. but I must avoid it.

Comment: There is always someone Putting a negative vote without explaining the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asotrans.htm):

> If an existing table has columns that require encryption, then use the
>   ALTER TABLE command in the following form:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY ( column_name column_type ENCRYPT,...);
> ```

The encryption process is atomic, and no data will be lost. The only way you'll lose the data is if you lose/destroy the wallet key, or drop the table/column yourself.

Comment: documentation is related to version 11. I have 10. I assume that the same applies under. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Rather than encrypting you can make the table READ ONLY through the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name READ ONLY;
```

Then no DDL or DML operations will affect the table.

Comment: i need encryption with Transparent Data Encryption